# how to make custom module in magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento

**How can the following be accomplish in Magento?**

Display a "Hello World" message using a controller/view/model approach. So, if I went to http://example.com/myController it would show the string 'Hello World'. Being able to show this string within the template of my website (for example, the header, footer, etc.) will be a bonus.

How to add a method to this controller (or a new controller if necessary), which interacts with a model, and performs the query `Select * FROM articles where id='10'` and returns the row (containing the columns `id`, `title`, `content`) to the controller?

And then use the controller to include a view, which would display this row. So going to http://example.com/myController/show_row (or something similar) would display the row within a view. (No need to be fancy, just a echo `$row->id`; or something similar would work.)

Comment: Have you even read the [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)? Check  this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write and ask a good question.

Comment: You can see https://github.com/UltimateModuleCreator too

Answer (score 4):

Your best option is to start with the long and detailed Alan Storm tutorial: [Magento for PHP MVC Developers](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_for_php_developers). Once you are done, continue with all the other subjects on [that same site](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento), as for example, magento API, magento config, etc.

Then, check all the questions and answers here in SO under the [magento tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento). Take a look too on the [Magento community boards](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards).

And last but not least, there are plenty of tutorials around there, do some searches on your preferred search engine and you will find a lot.